# How to add melee weapons in UDK?

Tags: udk

I am very new to game design and programming in Unrealscript for UDK. I have created a weapon mesh and imported it alongside it's animation set and created a start and end socket on it. I was wondering if anyone could help me create a weapon class for it and allow it to be used in the game?

Comment: I was unable to find tutorials that was up-to date. They were all outdated